# wxpython layout with sizers

Tags: python, layout, wxpython, sizer

I'm having difficulty getting my sizers to work properly in wxpython.  I am trying to do a simple one horizontal bar at top (with text in it) and two vertical boxes below (with gridsizers * the left one should only be 2 columns!! * inside each).  I want the everything in the image to stretch and fit my panel as well (with the ability to add padding to sides and top/bottom).  [image]

I have two main issues:
1. I cant get the text in the horizontal bar to be in the middle (it goes to the left)
2. I would like to space the two vertical boxes to span AND fit the page appropriately (also would like the grids to span better too).

Here is my code (with some parts omitted):

```
            self.LeagueInfoU = wx.Panel(self.LeagueInfo,-1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
            self.LeagueInfoL = wx.Panel(self.LeagueInfo,-1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
            self.LeagueInfoR = wx.Panel(self.LeagueInfo,-1, style=wx.BORDER_NONE)

            vbox  = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

            hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

            vbox2a = wx.GridSizer(12,2,0,0)
            vbox3a = wx.GridSizer(10,3,0,0)
            hbox1a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

            vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            vbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


            hbox1.Add(self.LeagueInfoU, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
            vbox2.Add(self.LeagueInfoL, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
            vbox3.Add(self.LeagueInfoR, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)

            vbox2a.AddMany([this is all correct])
            self.LeagueInfoL.SetSizer(vbox2a)

            vbox3a.AddMany([this is all correct])  
            self.LeagueInfoR.SetSizer(vbox3a)

            font = wx.Font(20, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
            self.Big_Header = wx.StaticText(self.LeagueInfoU, -1, 'Testing This')
            self.Big_Header.SetFont(font)

            hbox1a.Add(self.Big_Header, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)        
            self.LeagueInfoU.SetSizer(hbox1a)

            hbox2.Add(vbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
            hbox2.Add(vbox3, 0, wx.EXPAND)

            vbox.Add(hbox1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
            vbox.Add(hbox2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            self.LeagueInfo.SetSizer(vbox)
```

Comment: Could you put a runnable example up?

Comment: btw you only need 2 box sizers and 2 grid sizers. (grid sizers in a horizontal box sizer, then text and the horizontal sizer in a vertical sizer). You probably want to set proportion to 1 when adding the gridsizers too.

Comment: GP89 and Mike both nailed it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

[image]

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Title
        self.centred_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Title")
        main_sizer.Add(self.centred_text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE | wx.ALL, 3)

        # Grids
        content_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        grid_1 = wx.GridSizer(12, 2, 0, 0)
        grid_1.AddMany(wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=str(i)) for i in xrange(24))
        content_sizer.Add(grid_1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        grid_2 = wx.GridSizer(10, 3, 0, 0)
        grid_2.AddMany(wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=str(i)) for i in xrange(30))
        content_sizer.Add(grid_2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)

        main_sizer.Add(content_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this??

```
import wx



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,"Test Stretching!!")
        p1 = wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(500,100))
        p1.SetMinSize((500,100))
        p1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)

        hsz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        p2 = wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(200,400))
        p2.SetMinSize((200,400))
        p2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        p3 = wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(300,400))
        p3.SetMinSize((300,400))
        p3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

        hsz.Add(p2,1,wx.EXPAND)
        hsz.Add(p3,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sz.Add(p1,0,wx.EXPAND)
        sz.Add(hsz,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sz)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = MyFrame()
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure wx.GROW is the same as wx.EXPAND

Comment: yeah I guess your right ... for some reason I thought grow was vertical growth and expand was horizontal ...

Comment: Sadly, if you want to really, really center something, you have to put it inside of a horizontal sizer and put that inside a vertical one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        leftGridSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=10, cols=12, vgap=5, hgap=5)
        rightGridSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=10, cols=3, vgap=5, hgap=5)


        title = wx.StaticText(self, label="Main title")

        mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self), 0, wx.EXPAND)  # add a "spacer"
        mainSizer.Add(title, 0, wx.CENTER, wx.ALL, 10)

        for row in range(1, 11):
            for col in range(1, 13):
                lbl = "Row%s Col%s" % (row, col)
                leftGridSizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=lbl))
        hSizer.Add(leftGridSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 20)

        for row in range(1, 11):
            for col in range(1, 4):
                lbl = "Row%s Col%s" % (row, col)
                rightGridSizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=lbl))

        hSizer.Add(rightGridSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 20)
        mainSizer.Add(hSizer)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Sizers", size=(1600,600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

To learn about spanning rows, I recommend looking at the wxPython demo. I think that may only be supported in wx.GridBagSizer and the FlexGridSizer though. You can try the span parameter though. Also, it should be noted that wx.GROW and wx.EXPAND are one and the same. You might also want to check out the wiki for more information: http://wiki.wxpython.org/GridBagSizerTutorial