# wxpython sizers - does WX.EXPAND make a difference in spacers?

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer

Following good advice in the [BoxSizer from the ground Up](https://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp/ControlsPadding) tutorial I am refactoring code to factor out the wx.LEFT/RIGHT/TOP/BOTTOM flags into "spacers" - so:

```
horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl, 0, wx.LEFT, border)
```

becomes:

```
horizontal_sizer.Add((border, 0))
horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl)
```

For the case above I am sure they are completely equivalent. However if `wx.EXPAND` and a non zero proportion is specified as in:

```
horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl, proportion, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, border)
```

is this below:

```
horizontal_sizer.Add((border, 0))
horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl, proportion, wx.EXPAND)
```

completely equivalent to the above ? Visually they do seem identical but is there anything I am missing ? In other words does the `wx.EXPAND` influence the border and if yes how ?

Of course the examples above are trivial but in complex sizers layouts the above transformation (as suggested in the tutorial) greatly simplifies the code and makes common UI patterns stand out, that were plain unreadable in the mess of OR'ed flags and numbers.

**EDIT**: feedback on the Right Way to add a spacer would be appreciated. For instance I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17981624/281545):

```
mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self), 0, wx.EXPAND)  # add a "spacer"
```

or in the code I maintain people do:

```
horizontal_sizer.Add((0, 0), 1) # which seems equivalent to Add((0, 0))
```

Now in python there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it - here there are at least 4 - so some expert feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, proportion values and the `wx.EXPAND` flag are applied to spacers the same as for widgets. The item's minsize should be the size it was given when adding the spacer, (instead of being a property of the widget like usual.) You can easily implement some nicely resizing layouts with expandable sizers.

Using a `wx.StaticText` as a spacer works, but seems wasteful to me as there is no need to have a widget there, unless you need to do something special with it like setting a label at a later time or something like that.  I definitely would not call it a spacer though, it is a widget that happens to be blank at the moment.

Some of the more-than-one-way to do it came from a slight evolution of the C++ API over time, and wanting to maintain backwards compatibility, and also a bit of pythonization for the wrappers. However it is less messy than it was for a while, and the good news is that it is well documented in the Phoenix docs.  What is documented there should be compatible with Classic, and will continue to work with Phoenix into the future.

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Sizer.html

BTW, you didn't mention the convenience methods `AddSpacer` and `AddStretchSpacer`, so add another way to do it to the list. ;-) They do help with disambiguation however, so that is a nice addition.

Comment: Also I do not quite get what you mean by : "The item's minsize should be the size it was given when adding the spacer, (instead of being a property of the widget like usual." -> could you clarify that a bit ?

Comment: [`AddStretchSpacer`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Sizer.html#wx.Sizer.AddStretchSpacer) made me realize that _the proportion parameter takes effect even if the EXPAND flag is not specified_. That's news to me (and explains why people do `horizontal_sizer.Add((0, 0), 1) ` - it's actually equivalent to AddStretchSpacer. So why is there an EXPAND parameter if the proportion suffices to make the sizer expanded (backwards compat I guess). AddSpacer OTOH is discouraged in the turorial: https://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerFromTheGroundUp/ControlsPadding

Comment: I actually went ahead and posted that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/uPlSsjiV4zY. Sizers is one of the areas that wx does not endorse the "one right way" python principle and I am really, really, _really_ a fun of that principle :) Maybe time for a new wiki article (I have been going through and it does need some love) ?

Comment: The proportion value causes expansion in the same orientation as the box sizer, so horizontal expansion for a `wx.HORIZONTAL` box sizer, etc.  The `wx.EXPAND` flag causes the item to expand to fill the space in the other dimension.

Comment: Ok thanks - so `horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl, proportion, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, border)` is equivalent to `horizontal_sizer.Add((border, 0)); horizontal_sizer.Add(someControl, proportion, wx.EXPAND)` right ? IOW the border is not affected by the proportion vale or EXTEND flag ?

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent.